# Are there things that you can't test when applying TDD

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, integration-testing

I've been applying TDD to some new projects to get the hang of things, and I understand the basic flow: Write tests that fail, write code to pass tests, refactor if needed, repeat.

To keep the tests fast and decoupled, I abstract out things like network requests and file I/O. These are usually abstracted into interfaces which get passed through using dependency injection.

Usually development is very smooth until the end where I realize I need to implement these abstract interfaces. The whole point of abstracting them was to make it easily testable, but following TDD I would need to write a test before writing the implementation code, correct?

For example, I was looking at the tdd-tetris-tutorial https://github.com/luontola/tdd-tetris-tutorial/tree/tutorial/src/test/java/tetris. If I wanted to add the ability to play with a keyboard, I would abstract away basic controls into methods inside a Controller class, like "rotateBlock", "moveLeft", etc. that could be tested.

But at the end I would need to add some logic to detect keystrokes from the keyboard when implementing a controller class. How would one write a test to implement that?

Perhaps some things just can't be tested, and reaching 100% code coverage is impossible for some cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Perhaps some things just can't be tested, and reaching 100% code coverage is impossible for some cases?

I use a slightly different spelling: not all things can be tested at the same level of cost effectiveness.

The "trick", so to speak, is to divide your code into two categoies: code that is easy to test, and code that is so obvious that you don't need to test it -- or not as often.

The nice thing about simple adapters is that (once you've got them working at all) they don't generally need to change very much.  All of the *logic* lives somewhere else and that somewhere else is *easy to test*.

Consider, for example, reading bytes from a file.  That kind of interface looks sort of like a function, that accepts a filename as an argument and either returns an array of bytes, or some sort of exception.  *Implementing* that is a straight forward exercise in most languages, and the code is so text book familiar that it falls clearly into the category of "so simple there are obviously no deficiencies".

Because the code is simple and *stable*, you don't need to test it at anywhere near the frequency that you test code you regularly refactor.  Thus, the cost benefit analysis supports the conclusion that you can delegate your occasional tests of this code to more expensive techniques.

100% statement coverage was never the goal of TDD (although it is really easy to understand how you -- and a small zillion other people -- reached that conclusion).  It was primarily about deferring detailed design.  So to some degree code that starts simple and changes infrequently was "out of bounds" from the get go.

Answer (score 0):

You can't test everything with TDD **unit tests**. But if you also have integration tests, you can test those I/O interfaces. You can produce integration tests using TDD.

In practice, some things are impractical to automatically test. Error handling of some rare error conditions or race hazards are the hardest.